# mesa update breaks build

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mesa

Today a new mesa has been released on ubuntu 16.04.02
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
However it breaks my build, when I link my lib to libGL.so

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmFreeDevice'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetDevices'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetDevice'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmFreeDevices'
```

Downgrading to the previous versions manually fixes my issue.
Does someone else have this issue? Any idea to fix it cleanly?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/ or searching the Ubuntu bug database. If you can't find it but you can reproduce it, make a bug report.

Comment: You're right, wrong forum